# extjs MessageBox blocked the operation in the main window

Tags: javascript, extjs

`Ext.window.MessageBox` blocked the operation in the main window such as `data entry` in the following example. How to change it so that while the `MessageBox` is open or floating, user can still perform `data entry` in the main window?

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, so that I can edit it right away? You did not mention how you use MessageBox (show, alert,...). 5.1 is rather old. But basically you can create an Ext.Window with `model: false` and it should work.

Comment: As @Dinkheller wrote, you can create a non-modal window, but it's not `model: false`, but `modal: false`. `Ext.MessageBox` has that config also, at least in the newer versions. But `MessageBox` is just a window, you can create your own if you like.

Comment: haha, yes Peter is right. Should have been modal ;)

Comment: Thanks to all of you. `modal: false` worked